# Using javascript how to log keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, dom, keyboard-events

```
<input type="text"></input>

<script>
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
a.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  this.evt = evt || event;
var b = String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode);
 while(forEach(evt) {
     alert("You pressed " + b);
   }
};
</script>
```

This doesn't seems to be working. It should always alert the key when user presses a key.
The browser here is Chrome.

Comment: You need to close that script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you're calling a function you don't define (`forEach`), here:

```
while(forEach(evt) {
//    ^
```

If you look in the JavaScript console, you'll see an error related to that.

Also, you don't want to assign to an `evt` property on `this`:

```
this.evt = evt || event; // <== Don't do this
```

Just use the argument:

```
evt = evt || event;
```

And there's no reason for a loop if you're going to alert every keypress individually.

Also, `input` elements don't have closing tags. It should just be:

```
<input type="text">
```

or (in XHTML, and optionally in HTML):

```
<input type="text"/>
```

**not**:

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

And finally, note that some browsers use `which` for the keycode, others use `keyCode`. You can use `||` to use whichever the browser supplies:

```
String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode)
```

Here's a **minimal** update: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/itexaj/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/itexaj/1/edit)

```
<input type="text">
<script>
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
a.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || event;
  alert("You pressed " + String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode));
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a while loop.  Simply grab the key in a cross browser compliant manner, find its char equivalent and alert it.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
a.onkeypress = function(event) {
  //e.which & e.keyCode are for cross browser compliance
  alert(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.which)); 
};
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/VZEQe/